# Add button remove next to button browse for bootstrap custom-file class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With class bootstrap `custom-file` it create a beautiful upload controller as this

[image]

With this, I want to have the similar button Remove just left-side next to existing browse button for a purpose of remove file that fit with script.

```
<div class="custom-file" style="">
  <input type="" class="custom-file-input dropzone" id="images" multiple>
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

### Updated

I have found way to have Remove button as this

```
<div class="input-group mb-3"> 
    <div class="custom-file"> 
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file02"> 
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="file02">Choose file</label> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-group-append"> 
        <span class="input-group-text" id="">Remove</span> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Resulting in

[image]

But how can I align the remove button to the left instead? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

With the `order` property you can change the place of the element, try to place the class `order-2` to the element "Remove"

```
<div class="input-group-append"> 
     <span class="input-group-text order-2" id="">Remove</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add some CSS for "remove" & "browse" button in the same line.

```css
.custom-file .input-group {
    display: inline-block;
}

.custom-file  .input-group-append {
    display: inline-block;
}

.custom-file .input-group input[type=file] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Botstrap -->   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




    <div class="custom-file"> 
         
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file02"> 
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="file02">Browse</label> 
            </div> 
            <div class="input-group-append"> 
                <span class="input-group-text" id="">Remove</span> 
            </div> 
        
    
    </div>
```